# renaming column header texts in gridview with autogeneratecolumns = true

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, autogeneratecolumn

i have a gridview that displays query data from 1 table after the user presses a button with a code behind query, this gridview had autogeneratecolumns = false and i added the BoundField DataField header texts myself, for example, the first column in the db had the name "prd_nome" and i changed it to "nome", everything worked as it was supposed to.

now i've created a another table in the db, with a different name and different column names as well, i've also added another button with a code behind query to get data from that table but in order to display the data now the autogeneratecolumns = true, i tested the button and it works, however the header texts are the same as the column names and the ID column is also showing for both queries.

how do i hard code the header texts to what i want and how do i hide the ID column? via labels? via boundfield datafields? via the AS sql operator? 
if anyone could help me, i would appreciate because i'm a c# novice

here's the current gridview asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

here's the code of the button that passes a query from the first table:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ERPDQ].[dbo].[prd] WHERE prd_desc LIKE ('torta%')", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

          sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

and here's the code from the button that passes a query regarding the second table:

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ERPDQ].[dbo].[outra]", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please make your query in such way that header text you wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AutoGenerateColumns=True you can change the header texts of columns by using AS sql operator in your select statement (as you already suggested).

Although in general avoid using AutoGenerateColumns=True, because its inflexible. As you pointed out you get stuck by easy things such as hiding one column.

And here is an example how to hide ID column by using `RowDataBound` event

```
protected void rowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            var headerCell = e.Row.Controls[i] as DataControlFieldHeaderCell;
            if (headerCell != null)
            {
                if (headerCell.Text == "name_of_id_column")
                {
                    headerCell.Visible = false;
                    Page.Items["IDCellIndex"] = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        int idCellIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Page.Items["IDCellIndex"]);

        e.Row.Controls[idCellIndex].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention that there is one GridView or there are two GridView.

If there are two GridViews on your page then just add onrowdatabound event for both GridViews.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

If there is only 1 GridView then define two Boolean variable (btn1Click,btn2Click)before page load.On button1 click event set btn1Click to ture and btn2Click to false , on button2 click event set btn2Click to true and btn1Click to false and in OnRowDataBound event set columns name according to btn click.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  //supposing id is the first cell,change the index according to your grid
  // hides the first column
  e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; 

  if(btn1Click)
  {
     //to set header text
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Cell Text";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Cell Text";
     }
  }
  else if(btn2Click)
  {
     //to set header text
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Cell Text";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Cell Text";
      }
  }
}
```

Please mark both answers correct if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on GridView RowDataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  //supposing id is the first cell,change the index according to your grid
  // hides the first column
  e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; 

  //to set header text
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
  {
     e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Cell Text";
     e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Cell Text";
  }
}
```

Comment: here the gridview binding datasource is not fixed so you can't specify it as static

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, i'm sure i'll use some of the answers depending on the direction of the project after implementation.

regarding my gridview column header renaming issue, i found out that the AS operator works fine for the current needs, again i appreciate all the help provided